# Sublime Text 2 plugin: capture the selected text

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to write *my first* ST2 plugin (I'm also new to Python). What I want to do is capture the currently selected text. This is what I have thus far. I *thought* this would save all the selected text into the text variable but it looks like I'm only capturing the beginning and ending indices of the selection. Thus, if I select the first character in the buffer, my plugin callback prints "01". What I *want* is the **text** between index 0 and index 1.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class CopyOnSelectListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_selection_modified(self, view):
        selections = view.sel()
        text = ""
        for s in selections:
            text += str(s.begin())
            if not s.empty():
                text += str(s.end())
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ST2 API reference is [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html). `view.sel()` returns a [`RegionSet`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.RegionSet), an object containing the [`Region`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Region) of each selection. `Region.a` and `Region.b` are the integers referring to the beginning and ending, respectively, of the region. So, if your view contains

```
This is some text.
```

and you have selected `text`, `Region.a` would be 13 and `Region.b` would be 17. To actually get the contents of a Region, you need to use `view.substr(region)`. The following code will print the contents of each selection to the console:

```
import sublime_plugin

class PrintSelectionTextCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        for region in view.sel():
            print(view.substr(region))
```

You can run it by opening the console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>, making one or more selections in the open file, then running

```
view.run_command("print_selection_text")
```

from the console (assuming you've saved it as `Packages/User/print_selection_text.py`).